# Overlapping and placing element in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a comments box that displays a lit of existing comments. This box should overlap an image and be fixed to the bottom of the image. I have overlapped the box but the 'existing-comments-container' keeps stretching to the end of the page. The expected behavior is that it stretches across the width of the image container.

Here is an image which will hopefully make it clearer:

[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="full-view-container">
        <div class="overlay-inner-portrait">
            <img [src]="image.imagePath" alt="photo" (click)="closeImage()">
        </div>
        <div class="existing-comments-container">
            <div class="existing-comments" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
                <p class="commentor-name">{{comment.name}}</p>
                <p class="comment">{{comment.usersComment}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 4;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1;
    grid-template-rows: 1;
  }

 .full-view-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-row: 1 / -1;
      display: grid;
      grid-template: 1fr / 1fr; 
  }

  .overlay-inner-portrait {
    background: white;
    width: 450px;
    height: 580px;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;
    align-items: end;
  }

.overlay img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .existing-comments-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    align-self: end;
    justify-items: center;
    max-height: 100px;
    background: white; 
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to use image from internet with wanted size. Can you also add text that you want instead of `{{ }}`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean? What image from the internet are you referring to? The {{ }} syntax is Angular string interpolation.

Comment: You are using `src="image.imagePath"`. Can you please refer an usable image to us so we can debug easily

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Have resolved the issue now sorry. It seems the text from one of the users comments was very long and causing it to stretch

Comment: Answer your own question so future people can reproduce the example

Answer (score 0):

i found out the cause of this issue was that the text in one of the users comments box was very long and causing the boxes to stretch. I resolved this by setting a max-width on the p tag which has the class .comment